# Mapping an Oracle stored procedure result to a custom Java type (class)

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have to call a stored procedure in Oracle (11g) that uses a single IN OUT parameter. This parameter is an Oracle custom type defined as

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "SEPADD"."T_NAPRAVI_NALOG_TEST" IS OBJECT
 (
    I_INICIJALI              varchar2(3)  ,          
    I_STATUS                 number(1)        
 )
```

The actual type is more complex but I simplified it here for better readability. The Oracle procedure using this type (again simplified ) is defined as

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SEPADD"."GETNALOGTESTPROC"(nalog in out T_NAPRAVI_NALOG_TEST )
IS   
      BEGIN       
  nalog.I_INICIJALI := 'PC';         
      nalog.I_STATUS := nalog.I_STATUS + 3; 
END;
```

The Oracle custom type is mapped to a Java class that implements the SQLData interface. (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlcustommapping.html#implementing_sqldata)

```
 public class TNapraviNalog implements SQLData{

private int I_STATUS;
private String I_INICIJALI;
private String sql_type = "T_NAPRAVI_NALOG_TEST";
public String getSQLTypeName() {
        return sql_type;
    }
    public int getIStatus(){
     return this.I_STATUS;
}
    public String getIInicijali(){
        return this.I_INICIJALI;
    }
    public void setIInicijali(String in){
        I_INICIJALI = in;
    }
    public void setIStatus(int st){
        I_STATUS = st;
    }
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String type)
        throws SQLException {
        sql_type = type;
        I_INICIJALI = stream.readString();
        I_STATUS = stream.readInt();

    }

    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream)
        throws SQLException {
        stream.writeString(I_INICIJALI);
        stream.writeInt(I_STATUS);          
    }
}
```

Now, from my JDBC code I call the Oracle stored procedure in the following way

```
    Object obj=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    CallableStatement stmt=null;
    TNapraviNalog n = null;
    try{

          sqlQuery = "{call getnalogtestproc(?)}";

          Map m = conn.getTypeMap();
          m.put("sepadd.T_NAPRAVI_NALOG_TEST", Class.forName("ib.easyorm.db.TNapraviNalog"));//this maps the Java class to the Oracle custom type
          conn.setTypeMap(m);

          stmt=conn.prepareCall(sqlQuery);
          stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.STRUCT, "T_NAPRAVI_NALOG_TEST");
          stmt.setObject(1, paramValues.get(0) ); //paramValues.get(0) returns an instance of TNapraviNalog class

          stmt.execute();    

          obj = stmt.getObject(1, m);

          //obj = stmt.getObject(1,TNapraviNalog.class); this method is not implemented in the JDBC driver

    }catch(Exception e){
          throw new EasyORMException(e);
    }finally{
          closeResources(rs,stmt);
    }
    return obj;
```

Now, the problem is that, while I can get the result returned by the stored procedure, the result is not converted to a Java class (TNapraviNalog) so I have to do that manually. I can successfully
call the Oracle procedure with an instance of TNapraviNalog (  stmt.setObject(1, paramValues.get(0) ); ) but I can't get the result converted to TNapraviNalog. I really would like
to be able to have something like

```
 TNapraviNalog nalog = stmt.getObject(1, m);
```

However, this line will cause an exception ( **java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.STRUCT cannot be cast to ib.easyorm.db.TNapraviNalog**).
I'm guessing that the JDBC driver isn't aware of the actual type returned by the stmt.getObject(1,m) and thus can't make the conversion.

Does anybody know if this can be done using either plain JDBC or Hibernate?

**EDIT: The relevant code from an Oracle page** (link given in cihan seven's answer)

**Retrieving SQLData Objects from a Callable Statement OUT Parameter**

Consider you have an OracleCallableStatement instance, ocs, that calls a PL/SQL function GETEMPLOYEE. The program passes an employee number to the function. The function returns the corresponding Employee object. To retrieve this object you do the following:

1.Prepare an OracleCallableStatement to call the GETEMPLOYEE function, as follows:

```
 OracleCallableStatement ocs = (OracleCallableStatement)conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call GETEMPLOYEE(?) }");
```

2.Declare the empnumber as the input parameter to GETEMPLOYEE. Register the SQLData object as the OUT parameter, with the type code OracleTypes.STRUCT. Then, run the statement. This can be done as follows:

```
 ocs.setInt(2, empnumber); 
 ocs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.STRUCT, "EMP_OBJECT"); 
ocs.execute();
```

3.Use the getObject method to retrieve the employee object. The following code assumes that there is a type map entry to map the Oracle object to the Java type Employee:

```
 Employee emp = (Employee)ocs.getObject(1); //my comment-->this doesn't seem to work
```

If there is no type map entry, then getObject would return an oracle.sql.STRUCT object. Cast the output to the STRUCT type, because the getObject method returns an instance of the generic java.lang.Object class. This is done as follows:

```
STRUCT emp = (STRUCT)ocs.getObject(1);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appears to be in this line:

```
      m.put("sepadd.T_NAPRAVI_NALOG_TEST", Class.forName("ib.easyorm.db.TNapraviNalog"));//this maps the Java class to the Oracle custom type
```

This is the only line in which you are qualifying your `T_NAPRAVI_NALOG_TEST` type with the schema owner.  You refer to it in two other places without the schema name.

If you're connecting to your database as the `SEPADD` user (it seems you are), you can remove the schema owner prefix `sepadd.` from this line.  Alternatively, try changing the schema owner in the above line to upper-case.

Comment: I have tried adding the schema name everywhere, but it did not make any difference. Of couse, adding the schema name explicitly is never a mistake (regardless of the user name used), even though the user name is indeed sepadd as you've noticed. Removing the schema name doesn't help. The mapping seems OK though, as I can successfully call the procedure with an instance of TNapraviNalog. The problem is that the JDBC driver always returns the result as a STRUCT. It seems that it never tries to convert the result to a TNapraviNalog object.

Comment: @dsp_user: that's odd.  All I did to your code to get it working for me was to change the schema name in the line above to upper-case.  Removing the schema name also worked.  I'm using Oracle 11g XE version 11.2.0.2.0 on Windows 10 x64, and I've successfully run your code with each of four different Oracle JDBC driver JARs that I happened to have lying around: ojdbc14.jar version 10.2.0.5.0, ojdbc5.jar version 11.2.0.4.0, ojdbc6.jar version 11.2.0.2.0 and ojdbc7.jar version 12.1.0.2.0.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'get it working'? Do you get the result as a TNapraviNalog type. My code does work, but the result  is not converted to a TNapraviNalog, instead I always get a STRUCT object from stmt.getObject(1,m). Sure, I can parse the returned object and get the values just fine.

Comment: @dsp_user: when I say 'get it working' I mean 'have the value returned from the call to `stmt.getObject(1, m)` as a `TNapraviNalog` object rather than a `STRUCT` object'.

Answer (score 2):

You try to cast your Struct object to `TNapraviNalog`. But according to Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraoot.htm) you should first retrieve your struct as an `java.sql.STRUCT` object and then convert it to `TNapraviNalog` object.

try this:

```
java.sql.Struct jdbcStruct = (java.sql.Struct)stmt.getObject(1, m);
```

Comment: No, the documentation says that oracle.sql.STRUCT (superclass of java.sql.Struct) is returned when there is no type map defined. Anyway, a Struct (or STRUCT) can't be cast to a custom type (I've tried that)

Comment: Of course,  I get the result as oracle.sql.STRUCT (subclass of java.sql.Struct) but it can't be cast to TNapraviNalog.

Comment: Maybe you can define a _generic_ java class and try to cast `oracle.sql.STRUCT` to it and then cast your _generic_ class to  `TNapraviNalog` class?

Comment: When I say a STRUCT can't be cast to TNapraviNalog , I mean it will compile but it will always generate a ClassCast exception at runtime. This is expected since the two types don't extend the same classes. The Oracle documentation says that a custom type object could be obtained directly from CallableStatement.getObject() though . Don't know if this is a bug in the driver or perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that, whenever encountering "java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.STRUCT cannot be cast to some.java.Class"
The issue is either the class was not added to the TypeMap (not the case here) OR
the TNapraviNalog does not have a no arg constructor (which is the cause in this example)