# Calling a stored procedure with %ROWTYPE out param raise "Invalid column type: 1111"?

Tags: java, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-adf

I'm using JDev 11.1.1.7.0
and oracle Exp 11g DB

In my ADF application i'm trying to call a stored procedure, but i keep getting errors, the last one was "Invalid column type: 1111".

I think the problem is around this line

```
st.registerOutParameter(8,Types.OTHER);
```

My AppModuleImpl complete method:

```
    public Row callProcWithRowOut(Object[] bindVars) {
      CallableStatement st = null;
      try  {
        st = getDBTransaction().createCallableStatement("begin ADF_ITEM_SOLD(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);end;",getDBTransaction().DEFAULT);
        st.registerOutParameter(8,Types.OTHER);
        if (bindVars != null) {
          for (int z = 0; z < bindVars.length; z++) {
            st.setObject(z + 1, bindVars[z]);
          }
        }
        st.executeUpdate();

        return (Row)st.getObject(8);
      } catch (SQLException e)  {
        throw new JboException(e);
      } finally  {
        if (st != null) {
          try {
            st.close();
          }
          catch (SQLException e) {}
        }    
      }
    }
```

The trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111  
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getInternalType(OracleStatement.java:5344)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameterInternal(OracleCallableStatement.java:153)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:399)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:581)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:1765)
  at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.CallableStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleCallableStatementWrapper.registerOutParameter(Unknown Source)   
  at model.BC.AppModule.AppModule_AMImpl.callProcWithRowOut(AppModule_AMImpl.java:1793)
  at model.BC.Views.SalesInvoiceItems_VOImpl.insertItems(SalesInvoiceItems_VOImpl.java:54)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     
  at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCInvokeMethod.invokeMethod(DCInvokeMethod.java:657)
  at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCDataControl.invokeMethod(DCDataControl.java:2143)
  at oracle.adf.model.bc4j.DCJboDataControl.invokeMethod(DCJboDataControl.java:3118)
  at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCInvokeMethod.callMethod(DCInvokeMethod.java:261)
  at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.doIt(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:1635)
  at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCDataControl.invokeOperation(DCDataControl.java:2150)
  at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.invoke(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:740)
  at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PageLifecycleImpl.executeEvent(PageLifecycleImpl.java:407)     
  at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlActionBinding._execute(FacesCtrlActionBinding.java:252)
  at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlActionBinding.execute(FacesCtrlActionBinding.java:210)
  at view.backing.SalesInvoicesUpdate.insertItems_action(SalesInvoicesUpdate.java:281)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     
  at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(Unknown Source)     
  at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)    
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:46)
  at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
  at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:190)
```

What might be the problem?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What type of value are you expecting to be returned? I believe you need to use the Oracle-specific ORADATA mechanism for a structured type, or pick one of the standard types besides `Types.OTHER`.  If you specify `Types.OTHER`, Oracle (the JDBD driver) has no idea how to marshal the data.

Comment: Please don't post stack traces as blockquotes, it destroys the indentation and makes them unreadable. I fixed it for you this time

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks for your reply, The proc should return a %ROWTYPE of one my tables. I tried using Types.STRUCT but nothing. This is the problem i don't know which type to use in the java code to map the database row type, There is no Types.ROW available.

Comment: `%ROWTYPE` is a pseudo-typename, a placeholder for a structure type.  You'll need to know the actual row layout structure and perform the mapping yourself.  It's been a long time since I did this (15 years) and I've forgotten the details, but it was possible back then.  But the row type has to be known in advance.  I don't know if it's possible if you don't know the row type beforehand.

Comment: I know the row structure but i don't know how to perform this custom mapping.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/java.101/b10979/oraoot.htm

Comment: It's not normally possible to call a stored procedure returning a %ROWTYPE%. Only SQL types are supported (but not PlSql type ). Sometimes, using Oracle driver specific APIs you can retrieve even some PlSql types but your best bet to make this work is to modify your SP to return an Sql type.

Comment: @dsp_user well the reason i'm using %ROWTYPE is that i want to return multiple attributes that i'll use in the java method to insert a row in a table. So i figured why not return it as that table's %ROWTYPE instead of returning multiple OUT params. Is there a sql type that can hold multiple attributes?

Comment: You can create a custom object containing exactly the same fields as your %ROWTYP%. Or you can pack all your attributes in a single string (comma separated) and return it as a single varchar OUT argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already said in a comment, it's not normally possible to call stored procedures that return `non-sql` types (there're some exceptions to this using database specific APIs). Since `%ROWTYPE` is a `Pl/Sql` type, you will have to modify your procedure to return a supported (i.e. `SQL`) type. The simplest way to do that is to return a number of OUT parameters corresponding to your `%ROWTYPE` or you can even return a simple string/varchar (this string may contain a comma separated list of all your attributes) and then parse this string on the client (Java ) side.

I've also written a simple example avalable here that shows one way how to deal with this situation ( http://easyorm.info/SProc ). This example uses EasyORM library (simple `JDBC` wrapper), and not plain JDBC, but it should give you an idea how to modify your stored procedure.

You can also encode your `%ROWTYPE` as an Oracle object (`sql` type) and have your stored procedure return that object but this approach is more complex (see [Mapping an Oracle stored procedure result to a custom Java type (class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932990/mapping-an-oracle-stored-procedure-result-to-a-custom-java-type-class) for an example)

Comment: Ok I went the Object type, It returned a Struct object, but i can't access it. I created a class that implements SQLData like your link but it Cannot cast Struct object to it.

Comment: You still need to call to call *setTypeMap* on your Connection object (it's explained in the link)

Comment: Right noticed that 30 seconds before your comment ... Fixed and working ... Thank you dsp_user for you help